# Bounding box cutting of edges on custom ellipse

Tags: wpf, height, width, ellipse, bounding-box

I have a custom ellipse code shown bellow. I draw a rubber band using the ellipse setting the width  and height using two points, code shown bellow. However when I draw the ellipse the bounding box is cutting of the edges on the sides. I solved this issue before with using actual height and width, but this was in a stand alone application. When I integrated it with the rubber band drawing part, actual height and width don't work anymore, for some reason they don't get updated when I set the width and height. Do you know how can I fix it so that the edges don't get cut off.

```
 namespace WpfApplication4
{
    class Ellipse2 : Shape
    {
        EllipseGeometry ellipse;
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxShapeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextBoxShape", typeof(TextBoxShape), typeof(Ellipse2), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
        public TextBoxShape TextBoxShape
        {
            get { return (TextBoxShape)GetValue(TextBoxShapeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextBoxShapeProperty, value); }
        }
        public Ellipse2()
        {
            ellipse = new EllipseGeometry();

            this.Fill = Brushes.Transparent;
            this.Stroke = Brushes.Gray;
            this.StrokeThickness = 3;

        }
        protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
        {
            get
            {
                TranslateTransform t = new TranslateTransform(Width / 2, Height / 2);
                ellipse.Transform = t;
                ellipse.RadiusX = this.Width / 2;
                ellipse.RadiusY = this.Height / 2;

                return ellipse;
            }
        }
    }
}

     double width = Math.Abs(initMousePoint.X - currMousePoint.X);
     double height = Math.Abs(initMousePoint.Y - currMousePoint.Y);
     double left = Math.Min(initMousePoint.X, currMousePoint.X);
     double top = Math.Min(initMousePoint.Y, currMousePoint.Y);
     rubberBandShape.Width = width;
     rubberBandShape.Height = height;
     Canvas.SetTop(rubberBandShape, top);
     Canvas.SetLeft(rubberBandShape, left);
```

Comment: Please stop [prepending tags in your question titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/howto-writing-good-titles/10651#10651), it's not necessary and the page title automatically has the most popular tag added to it.

Comment: Is the only problem that `Ellipse2` is having the edges cut? I tried it out and it doesn't seem to handle stuff like `Margin` etc. Anyway, try to compensate for the `StrokeThickness`, like `ellipse.RadiusX = (this.Width / 2) - StrokeThickness / 2;`

Comment: @Meleak thanks it worked perfectly, I don't know how I didn't think of that. Post it as an answer if you want and I will accept it. Do you know by the way why the actual height and width don't get updated?

Comment: @mihajlv: Ok, added an answer :) I tried with `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` as well and it worked better then `Width` and `Height` for me. Not sure why you're having that problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to compensate for the StrokeThickness, like

```
ellipse.RadiusX = (this.Width / 2) - StrokeThickness / 2;
ellipse.RadiusY = (this.Height / 2) - StrokeThickness / 2;
```